# FaceTime call from Mac to iPhone 4S over 3G doesn't connect

Tags: macbook-pro, iphone, facetime

I tried to FaceTime my brother (who is using an iPhone 4s) from my MacBook Pro using the FaceTime app. The iPhone is on a 3G network, the MacBook is on my own Wi-Fi network.

The FaceTime app doesn't say that the iPhone is unavailable; it just keeps trying to connect, but the iPhone doesn't ring or do anything.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I assume that your brother's iPhone is on iOS 6 (which officially comes with the cellular FaceTime feature) and uses AT&T (which blocks this feature). I've heard someone say AT&T might start letting all iPhones use cellular FaceTime, but I believe the official word is that cellular FaceTime only works with AT&T if you have a Mobile Share plan or if you have an iPhone 5. Meanwhile you'll have to call him with Skype or Google Hangout, or he'll have to go to WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

Has your brother updated his phone to iOS 6?

If he has a jailbroken iPhone on iOS 5, he can use [this](http://www.redmondpie.com/enable-facetime-over-3g-natively-on-ios-5-or-5.0.1-the-easy-way/).

And if you're in the US, [this](http://lifehacker.com/5944597/can-i-use-facetime-over-3g4g) might help. To bypass all of this, just have him go on Wi-fi.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! While having links is nice, could you maybe summarize the most important parts of the links here, on-site, instead of just pointing users somewhere else? That'd be extremely helpful.